# NSPredicateEditor is invisible

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I tried so many ways to implement NSPredicateEditor but getting the blank editor view. Tried with a new project also but still i am getting the blank view of editor. I want to know what is the issue. is there any particular view on which this predicate is working. The code is
[image]

```
AppDelegate.h  
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject  {  
NSPredicate *predicate;  
}  
@end  

AppDelegate.m  
#define DEFAULT_PREDICATE @"firstname = 'John' AND lastname = 'Doe'"  
-(id)init  
{  
self = [super init];  
if (self != nil)  
{  
predicate = [[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:DEFAULT_PREDICATE] retain];  
}  
return self;  
}  
@end
```

Comment: We're not clairvoyant. Show us your code.

Comment: If there is a zero line code then also i am getting blank window, it should display the editor.

Answer (score 3):

Hidden in the documentation at NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate it is stated "After setting up the predicate editor, you typically send it a setObjectValue: message to restore a saved predicate"

so assuming you have a template in interface builder with a keypath of "Name" you would only need a line like this in code to display the templates:

```
[predicateEditor setObjectValue:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS \"\""]];
```

You could alternatively do this to load rows:

```
[predicateEditor addRow:self];
```